# Is there a way to grab the images rendered using PyQt5 QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have a QT5 browser that loads a page using QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView() and I am capturing the load_finished event to know when the web page is ready.

I need to be able to grab each of the images loaded on the page for further processing.

I know how to grab the image URLs from the page html source and download the image using URLLIB library. . But since the page is already loaded with all the images in the QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView() control, I would like to avoid making a round trip to the source web site for each of the images.

Is there a way I can read these images form QT local disk cache or ask the QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView() to give me the image data?

Thanks for the kind help.

Comment: There are no specific APIs for doing any of this. Some of the functionality is available via [web actions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#WebAction-enum), but it isn't really designed for programmatic access. Also, the cache doesn't seem to offer any obvious way to link a url with the image file stored on disk.

Comment: In the end I grabbed the image URLs from the html page and re-downloaded them using URLLIB in the background with multiple threads. While this is not ideal at all, the approach worked like a charm for a demo.